Mismatch of values after assigning values to a tensor by index
I am writing a PyTorch training code which constructs a class of algorithm. There is a step that needs to assign some values to an internal tensor. However, even if the code is only two lines, there is a bug. I find that the values of assigned tensor is different from the value for the assignment.
Here is the code of the class:
class PRODEN(Algorithm):
    """
    PRODEN
    Reference: Progressive identification of true labels for partial-label learning, ICML 2020.
    """

    def __init__(self, input_shape, train_givenY, hparams):
        super(PRODEN, self).__init__(input_shape, train_givenY, hparams)
        self.featurizer = networks.Featurizer(input_shape, self.hparams)
        self.classifier = networks.Classifier(
            self.featurizer.n_outputs,
            self.num_classes)

        self.network = nn.Sequential(self.featurizer, self.classifier)
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
            self.network.parameters(),
            lr=self.hparams["lr"],
            weight_decay=self.hparams['weight_decay']
        )
        train_givenY = torch.from_numpy(train_givenY)
        tempY = train_givenY.sum(dim=1).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, train_givenY.shape[1])
        label_confidence = train_givenY.float()/tempY
        self.label_confidence = label_confidence

    def update(self, minibatches):
        _, x, strong_x, partial_y, _, index = minibatches
        loss = self.rc_loss(self.predict(x), index)
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.confidence_update(x, partial_y, index)
        return {'loss': loss.item()}

    def rc_loss(self, outputs, index):
        device = "cuda" if index.is_cuda else "cpu"
        self.label_confidence = self.label_confidence.to(device)
        logsm_outputs = F.log_softmax(outputs, dim=1)
        #print(self.label_confidence.is_cuda)
        final_outputs = logsm_outputs * self.label_confidence[index, :]
        average_loss = - ((final_outputs).sum(dim=1)).mean()
        return average_loss

    def predict(self, x):
        return self.network(x)

    def confidence_update(self, batchX, batchY, batch_index):
        with torch.no_grad():
            batch_outputs = self.predict(batchX)
            temp_un_conf = F.softmax(batch_outputs, dim=1)
            '''the problematic codes begin'''
            self.label_confidence[batch_index, :] = temp_un_conf * batchY # un_confidence stores the weight of each example
            '''the problematic codes ends'''
            base_value = self.label_confidence.sum(dim=1).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, self.label_confidence.shape[1])
            self.label_confidence = self.label_confidence / base_value

The problem is in confidence_update . I find that the value of
self.label_confidence[batch_index, :]

is different from
temp_un_conf * batchY

after this assignment
self.label_confidence[batch_index, :] = temp_un_conf * batchY

only for few examples but the same for most examples. For example, for a batch size of 1024, there are about 4 examples at the first iteration and becomes larger afterwards. I am very frustrated with this problem and has tried many things:

The problem is only for CIFAR10 but does not exist for other datasets.

The data type for all tensors are Float32.

All the tensors are on the gpu.


What is wrong with my code?

When you say the values do not match, does it mean that you are printing the values right after self.label_confidence[batch_index, :] = ... for debugging?
